# Where are NSArrayController's bindings declared?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

When binding a NSArrayController, I see the following bindings available under controller content tab

- Content Array
- Content Array for Multiple Selection
- Content Object
- Content Set

However, I couldn't find those options inside the [Apple reference for `NSArrayController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), nor inside the actual `NSArrayController.h` itself. Where do they come from? And how do they differ from the `arrangedObject` property?

**Screenshot Below**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're [documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSArrayController.html) in [the Cocoa Bindings Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/), and they're not publicly declared in any header file. Xcode's knowledge of them is baked into Xcode, probably in some plug-in somewhere that comes with it.

> And how do they differ from the `arrangedObject` property?

`arrangedObjects` (plural) is an output. The array controller arranges its content objects, and the result of that is its arranged objects.

The bindings are inputs:

- `contentArray` is the main one, since it is an array controller.
- `contentSet` is an alternative for binding to Core Data to-many relationships, which are sets. I'm not sure whether it works with ordered sets; when the set isn't ordered, the order used by `arrangeObjects:` and manifest in `arrangedObjects` is determined by the array controller's sort descriptors.
- `contentArrayForMultipleSelection`, you don't normally need. The case in which you do need it is described quite well in the Cocoa Bindings Reference.
- `contentObject` is, as the CBR says, another array controller. Again, see the docs for its description of when you'd need it.

Content comes from one (or more) of the content bindings, is arranged (according to any sort descriptors the array controller may have) by `arrangeObjects:`, and is then available in the appointed order under `arrangedObjects`.

Comment: super clear, got it! Thanks. BTW, is there a way to declare what is bindable and what is not bindable in a class?

Comment: @Tony: Nope. All you can do is document it in comments in the header (or in separate documentation).

Comment: Actually I realized that there is indeed a way to declare key-value binding in the [NSKeyValueBindingCreation Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSKeyValueBindingCreation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). I think the "exposeBinding" method is what lets Xcode know that there is something that it can bind to.

Comment: @Tony: Nope. Last time I tried, at least, Xcode does not detect bindings from `exposeBinding:` messages. (Certainly it wouldn't know what options to make available, since that would depend on if/how `bind::::` is implemented.)